# UWSim install problem

Tags: ros, installation, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot get to install [UWSim](http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_UWSim). I'm running it on Precise (12.04) I thought it might have something to do with the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but since it seems correct I do not know what's up.
Here's the deal:

> graca@graca-A6J:~$ svn checkout http://uji-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/underwater_simulation
>
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/manifest.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/msg
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/msg/DVL.msg
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/msg/Pressure.msg
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/mainpage.dox
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_sensor_msgs/Makefile
> > A    underwater_simulation/stack.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/saveDataFile.sh
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/manifest.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/BulletPhysics.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/PressureSensor.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/VirtualRangeSensor.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SceneBuilder.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/VirtualCamera.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/osgPCDLoader.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ConfigXMLParser.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ObjectPicker.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/URDFRobot.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/osgOceanScene.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/KinematicChain.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SimulatedIAUV.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/InertialMeasurementUnit.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SphereSegment.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/DVLSensor.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SkyDome.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ViewBuilder.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/CustomWidget.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/GPSSensor.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/main.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ROSInterface.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/EventHandler.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SimulatorConfig.h.cmake
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/BulletPhysics.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/UWSimUtils.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/TextHUD.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/VirtualRangeSensor.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/HUDCamera.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/VirtualCamera.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ConfigXMLParser.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ObjectPicker.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/URDFRobot.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/KinematicChain.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/PressureSensor.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SphereSegment.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SceneBuilder.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/osgPCDLoader.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SkyDome.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/SimulatedIAUV.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/osgOceanScene.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/InertialMeasurementUnit.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/DVLSensor.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/UWSimUtils.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ViewBuilder.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/GPSSensor.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/HUDCamera.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/src/ROSInterface.h
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/g500ARM5.urdf
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/cirs.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/g500ARM5.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/ship_scene.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/cirs_stereo.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/ship.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/shapesTest.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/r2d2.urdf
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/UWSimScene.dtd
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/data/scenes/shipwreck.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/mainpage.dox
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/CMakeLists.txt
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/Makefile
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/gotoAbsolutePose.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setJointVelocity.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setVehiclePosition.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setVehicleActuators.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setVehicleDisturbances.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setVehiclePose.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setJointPosition.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setVehicleTwist.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/setVehicleVelocity.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/makeVehicleSurvey.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/UWSim/interface_examples/gotoRelativePose.cpp
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/manifest.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/config
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/config/dynamics_g500.yaml
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/src
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/src/dynamics.py
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/mainpage.dox
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/launch
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/launch/UWSim_g500_dynamics.launch
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/launch/dynamics.launch
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/CMakeLists.txt
> > A    underwater_simulation/underwater_vehicle_dynamics/Makefile
> > A    underwater_simulation/rosdep.yaml
> > A    underwater_simulation/CMakeLists.txt
> > A    underwater_simulation/Makefile
> > A    underwater_simulation/osgOcean
> > A    underwater_simulation/osgOcean/manifest.xml
> > A    underwater_simulation/osgOcean/osgOcean-1.0.1.patch
> > A    underwater_simulation/osgOcean/mainpage.dox
> > A    underwater_simulation/osgOcean/CMakeLists.txt
> > A    underwater_simulation/osgOcean/Makefile
> > U   underwater_simulation
> > Checked out revision 224.

> graca@graca-A6J:~$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH/home/graca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

> graca@graca-A6J:~$ rosdep install UWSim
>
> > ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
> > Missing resource UWSim
> > ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
> > ROS path [1]=/home/graca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
> > ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
> > ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43436/uwsim-install-problem/) by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on 2012-09-08**:
roswtf rosdep install UWSim

results in

Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Unable to load roslaunch file [rosdep]: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rosdep'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would seem that making use of roslocate and merge could be the answer to this quest. Still I didn't quite understand what happened and why it doesn't remember source setup.sh as I added it to .bashrc...

(New Problem, it just doesn't run the program. It goes all segm fault (core dumped))

---

Originally posted by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) with karma: 53 on 2012-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) on 2012-09-09**:
Hi, check this thread, you probably need to disable shaders: http://answers.ros.org/question/31871/segmentation-fault-on-running-uwsim/

**Comment by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on 2012-09-18**:
This worked! Thanks Mario